# awk to change field on match to another

Tags: awk

In the below I am trying to update/change the contents of `$1` in `f2` if there is a match in `$2` of `f2` and `$1` of `f1`. If there is no match then the line is printed as is in `f2`. The two commads below run but the `$1` value remains unchanged. Thank you :).

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]=$2; next } { if(a[$2]){$1=a[$2] }; print }' OFS="," 

gawk '{
    if(NR==FNR){
            a[$1]=$2;
            next
    }
    if($2 in a){
            $1=a[$2];
            print $0
    }
     else {
            print $0
    }
}' OFS="," f1 f2
```

**f1**  `tab-delimited`

```
file1   header
xxxx:7230   aaa11
xxxx:7231   yyyyy
xxxx:25478  zzzz
```

**f2**  `comma-delimited`

```
header1
header2
aaa11c,xxxx:7230,111,x1 111,yes
yyyyy,xxxx:7325,222,x2 222,
zzzz,xxxx:7329,222,x3 333,
```

**desired**

```
header1
header2
aaa11,xxxx:7230,111,x1 111,yes
yyyyy,xxxx:7325,222,x2 222,
zzzz,xxxx:7329,222,x3 333,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly you just forgot to set FS for each file:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} $2 in a{$1=a[$2]} 1' FS='\t' file1 FS=',' OFS=',' file2
```